# Explicit descriptions of the modular curves $Y(5)$ and $Y_1(5)$

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, modular-forms

The modular curves $Y(5)$ and $Y_1(5)$ associated to the congruence subgroups $\Gamma(5)$ and $\Gamma_1(5)$ are of genus 0. As such, they are nothing but 
the Riemann sphere $\mathbb P^1$ minus a finite subset of cusps:
$$ Y(5)=\mathbb P^1\setminus C(5)
\qquad Y_1(5)=\mathbb P^1\setminus C_1(5)\;.
$$
Moreover, it is known that $C(5)$ and $C_1(5)$ are of cardinality 12 and 4 respectively.

**Question :** what can be taken for the two sets of cusps $C(5)$ and $C_1(5)$?

Once $C(5)$ and $C_1(5)$ are explicitly given, I would like to find **an explicit rational expression** for the natural quotient map 
$$
Y(5)\longrightarrow Y_1(5)\,.
$$

Of course, I'm aware that this is very classical. 
A good reference would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you half the answer, and maybe you can work out the other half for yourself.

As I said in a comment a moment ago, there is no *canonical* isomorphism between $Y_1(5)$ or $Y(5)$ and an open subset of $\mathbf{P}^1$, so $C(5)$ and $C_1(5)$ will depend on your choice of uniformisation. So the real question here is "what are explicit modular functions giving isomorphisms $X_1(5) \cong \mathbf{P}^1$ and $X(5) \cong \mathbf{P}^1$?"

Such a modular function is called a **Hauptmodul** in the classical theory. For instance, the modular function defined by
$$ t(\tau) = q \prod_{n \ge 1} (1 - q^n)^{5 \left(\frac{n}{5}\right)}, $$
where $\left(\frac{n}{5}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol, is a Hauptmodul of level $\Gamma_1(5)$. The four cusps of $\Gamma_1(5)$ are the orbits of $\infty, 2/5, 1/2, 0$ on the boundary of the upper half-plane, and $t(\tau)$ takes these to $0, \infty, (11 \pm 5\sqrt{5})/2$ respectively. (I got these formulae from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X08001224) after a quick web search.) So this gives an explicit isomorphism between $Y_1(5)$ and $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{C}) - \{ 0, \infty, (11 \pm 5\sqrt{5})/2\}$.

Now you can go and look for a Hauptmodul for $\Gamma(5)$ and see if you can repeat this calculation (although it will, of course, be quite messy).